# If a Duskblade channels shocking grasp can he use it as a touch attack?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

My Duskblade channels shocking grasp,and misses with his attack. Next round he full action attacks and misses with his first attack. For his second attack could he take his hand off his two handed weapon and make a touch attack with his shocking grasp? As per the players guide on holding the charge you do not loose the spell until you hit with it or cast another spell. I previously asked if you channeled shocking grasp if you could change the energy type by using gauntlets of energy transformation and was told the shocking grasp isn't in the weapon it channels when you make the hit. So if you cannel the spell in round 1 and miss you are still holding the spell in round 2. Holding the spell from round 1 you use the full attack action in round 2, miss with your weapon attack in round 2. As your second attack in round 2 can you take your hand off your two handed weapon as a free action and make a touch attack as your second attack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assumption that the spell is "in your hand", especially the particular hand you cast it on originally is not following RAW. As written, there is no specification and you can muck around with weapons etc until you discharge the spell. The discharge rules do not prevent this.

So in this scenario you can simply choose that the Duskblade tries to hit with his second attack using either his weapon or as an unarmed strike or an unarmed touch attack.

In my view, the confusion comes from mistaking a hit roll and damage roll as representing a single strike with a single weapon when it is really an abstraction of 6 seconds combat using the weapons to hand. Thus there are not rules for a pommel strike when it can easily be represented by a low a roll with your damage dice.

http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm
http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm#fullRoundActions
http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/shockingGrasp.htm

Answer (score -1):

You can't cast a spell to replace a weapon attack in a Full Attack, because spells aren't weapons. Because:

- A Full Attack takes a Full Round Action, and is resolved by making weapon attacks following your BAB.
- Casting Shocking Grasp is a Standard Action, and is resolved by making a melee touch attack.

Quite simply, a spell does not count as a weapon, and you use your weapons to resolve a Full Attack.

However, being a duskblade, you can channel the spell simply by hitting the enemy with your sword, which can be done during your Full Attack. However, the damage is only applied on one attack.
Also, I see no reason why you would release your weapon to apply it with your hand, instead of simply channeling it. While the weapon damage is only applied when you beat a creatures total AC, the spell damage is applied once you beat it's touch AC, just like if you were casting the spell normally.

Comment: There is something missing here. You should address why it would/wouldn't work if under the effects of [Haste](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/haste.htm). You should also address why it would/wouldn't work due to the duration be instantaneous.

Comment: You're answering the wrong scenario. @Nathtfm didn't claim to cast a spell and full-attack in the same round. He's using the "holding the charge" rule.

Comment: @topquark I posted my answer, then the asker edited his question. I'll see if I can edit it again to make it relevant again, else I'll simply delete it.

Comment: @Ruut I cannot see what Haste and durations exactly have to do with the question. Was in the question, but it got edited? Is there something vital about those that I am missing?

Comment: The logic to use a touch attack instead of his melee attack is most likely the AC of his opponent. I think one can re-formulate the question to 'does the sword hold the charge after channelling or is it still on his hand?'. To which the answer is 'the charge is still in the hand', allowing him to simply make the touch attack, using the regular rules of shocking grasp. However, I would like to know where get the part from that the spell still lands if his weapon misses?

Comment: @BasJansen Described in the descriptor of the channeling ability, the spell remains a touch-spell. This means that the spell hits once the Touch AC is beaten, which is generally *lower* than the overall AC. The weapon's damage is only applied once the overall AC is beat. Look at it like this: Shocking grasp electrocutes the target when you manage to touch them. If you manage to touch the armour of your target, it simply runs through it. However, a sword cannot do such a thing. When you channel the spell through your sword, and the sword hit armour, the sword doesn't damage the target, ...

Comment: @BasJansen But the spell is released, and runs through the armour, thus damaging the enemy. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: The Arcane Channeling ability explicity states at the end of the first paragraph "...If the melee attack is successful, the attack deals damage normally, then the effect of the spell is resolved." You cannot miss your melee attack and still deal spell damage because you rolled higher than the opponent's touch AC. Depending on which way it is delivered it needs to beat the relevant AC.